# How to display the correct specific data on the screen from RangePicker antdesign in react js multisteps Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I was trying to display the input data from RangePicker like start date and end date but the date data are not like I was expecting to be. All the input date data are displayed with the same value. The data I would like to display is>>>

```
{
    "0": {.....},
    "1": {
        "school_0": "Maple Leaf University",
        "degree_0": "BA(Econ)",
        "studyDates_0": [
            "2014-05-01T14:10:26.289Z",
            "2018-10-31T14:10:26.289Z"
        ],
        "school_1": "Oak Ridge Technical School",
        "degree_1": "BCS",
        "studyDates_1": [
            "2020-03-01T14:10:50.636Z",
            "2023-06-30T14:10:50.636Z"
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "position_0": "Customer Support",
        "company_0": "A Company",
        "description_0": "Responsibility No.1",
        "workingDates_0": [
            "2016-06-01T14:11:30.024Z",
            "2017-08-31T14:11:30.024Z"
        ],
        "position_1": "Frontend Developer",
        "company_1": "B Company",
        "description_1": "Responsibility No.2",
        "workingDates_1": [
            "2022-08-01T14:12:04.888Z",
            "2023-09-22T14:12:04.888Z"
        ]
    }
}
```

My codes to trigger the expected data >>>

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Resume.css";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export const Resume = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const formValues = location.state;
  const educationData = Object.keys(formValues[1]);
  const experienceData = Object.keys(formValues[2]);
  const skillsData = Object.keys(formValues[3]);
  const projectsData = Object.keys(formValues[4]);

  return (
    <div className="resume">
      <div className="d-flex">
        <div className="section1">
          <h1 className="header">{formValues[0].name}</h1>
          <div className="basicInfoData">
            <img src={formValues[0].image.file.thumbUrl} alt="avatar" />

            <p>
              <i class="fa-regular fa-envelope-open"></i> {formValues[0].email}
            </p>
            <p>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen-button"></i>{" "}
              {formValues[0].phone}
            </p>
            <p>
              <i
                class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"
                style={{ color: " #0072b1 " }}
              ></i>{" "}
              {formValues[0].linkedIn}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="educationData">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            {educationData.map((index, value) => {
              const school = formValues[1][`school_${value}`];
              const degree = formValues[1][`degree_${value}`];
              const studyStartDate = formValues[1][`studyDates_${index}`];
              const studyEndDate = formValues[1][`studyDates_${index}`];

              if (school && degree) {
                const formattedStudyStartDate =
                  dayjs(studyStartDate).format("YYYY MM DD");
                const formattedStudyEndDate =
                  dayjs(studyEndDate).format("YYYY MM DD");

                return (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-solid fa-school"
                        style={{ color: " #3B3086 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {school}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap"
                        style={{ color: " #3B3086 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {degree}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-solid fa-user-clock"
                        style={{ color: " #3B3086 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {formattedStudyStartDate} - {formattedStudyEndDate}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                );
              }

              return null;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="section2">
          <div className="experienceData">
            <h2>Experience</h2>
            {experienceData.map((index, value) => {
              const company = formValues[2][`company_${value}`];
              const position = formValues[2][`position_${value}`];
              const workingStartDate = formValues[2][`workingDates_${index}`];
              const workingEndDate = formValues[2][`workingDates_${index}`];

              if (company && position) {
                const formattedWorkingStartDate =
                  dayjs(workingStartDate).format("YYYY MM DD");
                const formattedWorkingEndDate =
                  dayjs(workingEndDate).format("YYYY MM DD");

                return (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-solid fa-building"
                        style={{ color: " #7291F9 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {company}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-user"
                        style={{ color: " #7291F9 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {position}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <i
                        class="fa-regular fa-calendar"
                        style={{ color: " #7291F9 " }}
                      ></i>{" "}
                      {formattedWorkingStartDate} - {formattedWorkingEndDate}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                );
              }

              return null;
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="skillsData">
            <h2>Skills</h2>
            {skillsData.map((index, value) => {
              return (
                <ul key={index}>
                  <li>
                    <i
                      class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"
                      style={{ color: "#00d604" }}
                    ></i>{" "}
                    {formValues[3][`skillItem_${value}`]}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="projectsData">
            <h2>Projects</h2>
            {projectsData.map((index, value) => {
              return (
                <ul key={index}>
                  <li>
                    <i
                      class="fa-solid fa-link"
                      style={{ color: "#3B3086" }}
                    ></i>{" "}
                    {formValues[4][`projectList_${value}`]}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Can somebody please help me where I did wrong and How can I fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.